# Count of LotusNote Item via VBA

Tags: excel, lotusscript, vba

I have a VBA macro that gets some data from a LotusNotes application.  Most of it works well but I don't get around retrieving the number of elements in an Item.

For example:

```
Dim DomSession As Object
Dim DomDir As NotesDatabase
Dim DomContacts As NotesView
Dim DomDoc As NotesDocument

While Not (DomDoc Is Nothing)
GetItemValue("name of item")(0)  
Set DomDoc = DomContacts.GetNextDocument(DomDoc)
Wend
```

GetItemValue("name of item")(0)  gets me the first or only value of the Item. However, if there are more elements in an Item, which happens, than I do not know how many.  Looping trough the indexes (i) results in a runtime error in VBA as it loops until the list gets out of bounds.

In LotusScript itself there is @Count that should do what I want, but this does not work via VBA.  Any suggestions?

Comment: A shot in the dark. It's been long since I worked with Lotusscript. Try something like this `MyAr = doc.GetItemValue( "name of item" )` and then `Ubound(MyAr)` to get the count of itmes?

Comment: Thanks! This does seem to do the trick.

Comment: Actually, it's Ubound(MyAr)+1, since array element 1 is at index 0.

Answer (score 2):

GetitemValue returns an array with all values in an item.

As pointed out in the comments you simply assign the result to a variable and cycle through using ubound:

```
Dim DomSession As Object
Dim DomDir As NotesDatabase
Dim DomContacts As NotesView
Dim DomDoc As NotesDocument
Dim varValues

While Not (DomDoc Is Nothing)
    varValues = DomDoc.GetItemValue("name of item")
    max = ubound( varValues )
    For i = 0 to max
       yourValue = varValues(i)
       '- do whatever you want with values
    Next
    Set DomDoc = DomContacts.GetNextDocument(DomDoc)
Wend
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.